# How to validate a string which is seperated by a colon, but not an the end of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently trying to validate an input, which is seperated by colons. But it's possible, that the user enters a single word without being followed by a colon. It should be not allowed to end the string with a colon. Only lowercase letters are allowed. The pattern should allow further chaining as pointed out by the examples below.

These are the allowed test strings:

```
auto
auto:vehicle
auto:vehicle:face
auto:vehicle:face:subject
auto:vehicle:face:subject:classic
```

This is what i've got so far, bit it isn't working as expected:

`/([a-z]+:[a-z]+:?)/g`

How can i tell the pattern to check if its only one word, so that a following colon isn't necessary and how can i allow the pattern the repeating of matches (chaining)?

Any help would be gladly appreciated :)

Comment: In future consider waiting longer before selecting an answer. Quick selections can discourage other answers, must be retracted if readers later find a fault with the answer and, imo (others will disagree), are discourteous to those still working on their answers. There's no rush. I would encourage you to wait at least a couple of hours. Some members wait much longer, giving then-offline members a chance to respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
^[a-z]+(?::[a-z]+)*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dc4Fqt/1/)

The regex reads, "match one or more lower case letters at the beginning of the string, followed by zero or more strings, each beginning with a colon and followed by one or more lower case letters, followed by the end of the string".

Answer (score 1):

this should work as well

`^([a-z]+:)*[a-z]+$`

match lowercase letters ending with `:` 0 to n times and then it has to end with lowercase letters without a colon